# Using characteristic functions to establish convergence

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions, poisson-distribution

[image]

So I have found the Characteristic function of the variable $X_ \lambda$ to be:

$$\psi_{X_\lambda}(t) = \psi_{b(\lambda)(Y_\lambda-\lambda)}(t)=\mathbf Ee^{itb(\lambda)(Y_\lambda-\lambda)}=\mathbf E^{itY_\lambda b(\lambda)}e^{-it\lambda b(\lambda)}=e^{-it\lambda b(\lambda)} \mathbf Ee^{it Y_\lambda b(\lambda)} = e^{-it\lambda b(\lambda)} \psi_{Y_\lambda}(tb(\lambda))$$

Now as $Y_\lambda$ is a Poisson random variable we get:
$$e^{\lambda(e^{itb(\lambda)}-1)-it \lambda b(\lambda)}$$

And this is where I am stuck at I don't know how to continue to establish convergence of $X_\lambda$ any hints?

Comment: $$e^z-1-z\sim\tfrac12z^2\implies\lambda\cdot(e^{itb(\lambda)}-1)-it \lambda b(\lambda)=\lambda\cdot(e^{itb(\lambda)}-1-it b(\lambda))\sim\lambda\cdot\left(-\tfrac12t^2b^2(\lambda)\right)$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your answer please? Sorry if it takes too much time!

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the parts of my comment which elude you please?

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at $e^z-1-z\sim\tfrac12z^2$

Comment: This is the expansion of the exponential at zero, which reads $$e^z=1+z+\tfrac12z^2+o(z^2).$$

Comment: Oh right... Sorry for the confusion I thought that the ~ sign meant something like $Z \sim N(0,1)$. I should be able to work it out from here! Thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @Did's comment, we have
$$ \psi_{X_\lambda}(t) = e^{\lambda\left(e^{itb(\lambda)}-1-itb(\lambda)\right)} $$
For sufficiently large $\lambda$, this is approximately equal to
$$ e^{\lambda\left(-\frac12 t^2b^2(\lambda)\right)}.$$
Choosing $b(\lambda) = \lambda^{-\frac12}\sigma$ (where $\sigma>0$), we have
$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\psi_{X_\lambda}(t) = e^{-\frac12\sigma^2t^2}, $$
which implies that $$X_\lambda\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2).$$

Comment: I have 2 questions:
1) If I choose $b(\lambda) = \lambda ^ {\frac{-1}{2}}$ Then I would get a standard normal distribution right? 
2) I don't understand why for sufficiently large $\lambda$ the $O(1)$ terms disappear

Comment: 1) Correct ($\sigma=\sigma^2=1$).
2) That follows from Taylor's theorem.